# How can I get the Materialize CSS framework (sass version) to not be responsive on large screens only

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, materialize, responsive

I am using Materialize CSS SASS version to build a website. I would like to make it non-responsive for large screens only (anything above medium/tablet view) but I would like to keep it responsive for medium and small screens. How can I do this?

An example of a website that kind of does this is the Tesla website:

https://www.tesla.com/en_GB/

```
// 12. Global
// ==========================================================================

// Media Query Ranges
$small-screen-up: 601px !default;
$medium-screen-up: 993px !default;
$large-screen-up: 1201px !default;
$small-screen: 600px !default;
$medium-screen: 992px !default;
$large-screen: 1200px !default;

$medium-and-up: "only screen and (min-width : #{$small-screen-up})" !default;
$large-and-up: "only screen and (min-width : #{$medium-screen-up})" !default;
$extra-large-and-up: "only screen and (min-width : #{$large-screen-up})" 
!default;
$small-and-down: "only screen and (max-width : #{$small-screen})" !default;
$medium-and-down: "only screen and (max-width : #{$medium-screen})" !default;
$medium-only: "only screen and (min-width : #{$small-screen-up}) and (max-
width : #{$medium-screen})" !default;
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically the Tesla site is responsive on the large screen, as that background image extends 100% no matter the width.

But I see what you are saying from 640px to about 960px the tesla image has a minimum fixed width that extends past the browser window..

If you are starting mobile-first then at your large screen breakpoint, make sure all relevant containers have a minimum fixed width.

```
.hero {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 960px;
}
```

That's all I can say without any HTML or CSS provided

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. The Tesla example was the closest I could find, however unlike the Tesla website I'd like it to be completely non responsive on large screens. I made a basic code pen example with the Materialize css framework. https://codepen.io/Lujane/pen/VXXEox. However I am using the SASS version. If there is anymore information I can provide please let me know.

Comment: So for example in that pen, you can add this css: @media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  nav {
    width: 2000px;
  }
}

And see how at 800px, the header is no longer 100% but a fixed width that is bigger than the screen. You would have to look through all your elements that would need this sort of treatment. Not sure why you want to do this but happy coding :)